# Xamarin Plugin.BLE // I can't pull data

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, bluetooth, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

There is a device that measures tire tread depth and air pressure.
I made a connection but I can't pull data. Can you direct me on how to do it?
I pulled data using Android DLLs but failed with plugin.ble.
Note: The state in the device object disconnect after a certain time. I do not know the reason.

Source code I wrote

Part-1

```js
bluetoothBLE = CrossBluetoothLE.Current;
adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
list = new ObservableCollection();
DevicesList.ItemsSource = list;
```

Part-2

```js
adapter.ScanTimeout = 10000;
adapter.ScanMode = ScanMode.Balanced;
adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (obj, a) =>
{
if (!list.Contains(a.Device))
list.Add(a.Device);
};
await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
```

Part-3

```js
device = DevicesList.SelectedItem as IDevice;
await adapter.StopScanningForDevicesAsync();
var connectParams = new ConnectParameters(true, true);
await adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device, connectParams);
```

Part-4

```js
var xservices = await device.GetServicesAsync();
var xservice = await device.GetServiceAsync(xservices[0].Id);
var Characteristic = await xservice.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
var xxxcharacteristicread = await xservice.GetCharacteristicAsync(xitem.Id);
var c = await xxxcharacteristicread.ReadAsync();
```

Version of the Plugin: 2.1.1

Platform: iOS 10.1 / Android 7.0

Device: samsung note 5 /i Phone 7

Comment: do you get errors or exceptions?